# DataSet in SilverLight 4

Tags: dataset, silverlight-4.0

Dataset is not available while using silverlight 4. I added System.Windows.Data but i cant use Dataset. whether i have to add anyother Files? anybody help me plz...

Answer (score 0):

DataSet isn't supported in Silverlight, use ADO.NET Data Services or .Net RIA Services